# How do I Copy a Sharepoint List A to include metadata fields in List B?

Tags: custom-list, managed-metadata

Ok. I have a SharePoint List A and I need to copy to another list B (list B will have different permissions). The List are almost identical, but List B is (missing one column).

Is there any way "Out of the box" (without code or utilities) to copy List A to List B and  also include the metadata columns in list B?

Comment: Can all the visible columns of List B remain In sync with columns of  List A for any changes or new items?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the "save as template" feature:

1. Go to the list you want to copy.
2. Go to the List Settings
3. Go to "Save List as template"
4. Type in your File name and Template name
5. Click Save
6. Go to Site Actions -> More Options... (to create content)
7. You will see the template you just created, select it and choose a name
8. Click Create.

You can then delete the fields you don't want after that.